The provided view controller is not being presented - Google mobile ads
I'm trying to display an interstitial add on a button tap in my Flutter application, the ad is loaded fine, but when I try to show it, it notifies the following callback onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent and throws following error:

error(code: 17, domain: com.google.admob, message: the provided view
controller is not being presented.)

Here is the code to open the ModalBottomSheet
  void displayAd() async {
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
      interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback =
          FullScreenContentCallback(onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
        convert();
      }, onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, adError) {
        print(adError); // the provided view controller is not being presented
      });
      interstitialAd!.show();
    } 
  }



Is your modal already on the screen? I've seen this error when I tried to display interstitial ad from the view controller in viewDidLoad. The fix was to wait until the view was loaded (using viewDidAppear).
